# Can't access json values in react native

Tags: json, react-native

I've been using React-native recently (it's my first time to be honest).

I'm retrieving values from an api and i'm trying to display them in a Text tag. But i don't know how to access these values.

So, this is my code  :

```
export const Home = () => {
  
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const getApiInformations = async () => {

    const response = await fetch('https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=margarita');
    const responseJson = await response.json();
    setData(responseJson);
  }
  
  useEffect(() => {
    getApiInformations();
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <View>
        <Text>
            {
              I want to put the values here like : data.idDrink, data.OtherValue,...
            }
        </Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

In {data.drinks} i have :

```
0: {idDrink: '11007', strDrink: 'Margarita', strDrinkAlternate: null, strTags: 'IBA,ContemporaryClassic', strVideo: null, …}
1: {idDrink: '11118', strDrink: 'Blue Margarita', strDrinkAlternate: null, strTags: null, strVideo: null, …}
2: {idDrink: '17216', strDrink: "Tommy's Margarita", strDrinkAlternate: null, strTags: 'IBA,NewEra', strVideo: null, …}
3: {idDrink: '16158', strDrink: 'Whitecap Margarita', strDrinkAlternate: null, strTags: null, strVideo: null, …}
4: {idDrink: '12322', strDrink: 'Strawberry Margarita', strDrinkAlternate: null, strTags: null, strVideo: null, …}
5: {idDrink: '178332', strDrink: 'Smashed Watermelon Margarita'
```

Thanks for your help :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `.map()` functionality in javascript. For example:

```
{data && data.map((element) => {
    return <Text key={element.idDrink}>ID: {element.idDrink} Name: {element.strDrink}</Text>
})}
```

Comment: Couple of suggestions: 1. the state is `data`, not `responseJson`, 2. don't forget the `key` property on each `<Text>`.

Comment: Thank you. Made those changes.

Comment: I did what you said but then i get that error : typeerror: cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') because before doing data.map i have to do data.drinks.map. But if do data.map exactly like you i have this error : typeerror : data.map is not a function.

Comment: Can you `console.log(responseJson)` and show that?

Comment: When I do console.log(responseJson), first i have an empty array like that : [] and then i have automatically a second line like that : {drinks: Array(6)} (it's due to the useEffect() i suppose )

Comment: Oh ! No sorry i was not adding the part with "data &&" can you explain why do i have to add this ?

Comment: Basically, it takes some time for the API call to return and set the value of the variable `data`. Until that happens it will be `undefined`. So we are checking if something is stored in `data` (or if it is not `undefined` or not `null`) by the statement `data &&`.

Comment: `data &&` is similar to `if (data)`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help ! I have on last question i just tried to add multiple Text tag in my return of map() but i had warning : Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. Do you know why do I have that ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28329550/14555991

Comment: I think it'll be useless to open another subject for that, but there is a problem with the map() function with the Image tag.

I have a property *strDrinkThumb* in my json, it's an url image, but when i do 

```
 data.drinks && data.drinks.map((element) => {
                return <View>
                        <Image key={element.idDrink} source={{uri: element.strDrinkThumb}} />
                        <Button title="Details"></Button>
                      </View>
```

My Image tag don't display anything.

Comment: Not sure but try this: `source={require({element.strDrinkThumb})}`

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work

Comment: Oh i found the solution i just add style={{width: 400, height: 400}} and it worked perfectly. Thank you again sir. :)